# Buffer not large enough for pixels

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I get the error that my buffer is not large enough for pixels. Any recommendations? The Bitmap b should be the same size as the gSaveBitmap that I'm trying to place its pixels into.

```
if(gBuffer == null)
        {
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(gBitmap, mWidth, mHeight, false);
            //gBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(b.getRowBytes()*b.getHeight()*4);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,  100,  stream);
            gBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(stream.toByteArray());
            b.recycle();
        }
        gSaveBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(gBuffer);
```

Update: The below code gives the exact same error without any compression involved.

```
if(gBuffer == null)
        {
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(gBitmap, mWidth, mHeight, false);

            int bytes = b.getWidth()*b.getHeight()*4;
            gBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);
            b.copyPixelsToBuffer(gBuffer);              
            b.recycle();
        }
        gSaveBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(gBuffer);
```

Update: Solved the issue by doubling the size of gBuffer. Perhaps someone can tell me why this is the correct size. Also ... the picture is in the wrong rotation, needs rotated 90 degrees. Any ideas how the data would need to be rearranged in gBuffer?

```
gBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(b.getRowBytes()*b.getHeight()*2);
```

Comment: PNGs have 4 channels (RGBA) usually and you might be trying to stuff the data into a 3-channel bitmap (RGB) which would give this error

Comment: Srdjan, wouldn't JPEG CompressFormat fix that issue since its 24 bit RGB values?

Comment: Actually, if you're just copying an image, why don't you use something like gSaveBitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true) instead of working with buffers/streams?

Comment: the gSaveBitmap is actually set on a canvas so it can be saved to a file later, the problem is that if i were to simply Draw a bitmap, it is not saved to the canvas.

Comment: When you copy the pixels to the gBuffer, it's position will be at the end. You should call .position to seek to the beginning otherwise your copy from will read from the end.

Answer (score 3):

I think I might have solved this one-- take a look at the source (version 2.3.4_r1, last time Bitmap was updated on Grepcode prior to 4.4) for [Bitmap::copyPixelsFromBuffer()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/graphics/Bitmap.java#Bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer%28java.nio.Buffer%29)

```
public void copyPixelsFromBuffer(Buffer src) {

     checkRecycled("copyPixelsFromBuffer called on recycled bitmap");

     int elements = src.remaining();
     int shift;
     if (src instanceof ByteBuffer) {

         shift = 0;

     } else if (src instanceof ShortBuffer) {
         shift = 1;

     } else if (src instanceof IntBuffer) {
         shift = 2;

     } else {

         throw new RuntimeException("unsupported Buffer subclass");

     }

     long bufferBytes = (long)elements << shift;
     long bitmapBytes = (long)getRowBytes() * getHeight();

     if (bufferBytes < bitmapBytes) {

         throw new RuntimeException("Buffer not large enough for pixels");

     }

     nativeCopyPixelsFromBuffer(mNativeBitmap, src);

 }
```

The wording of the error is a bit unclear, but the code clarifies-- it means that your buffer is calculated as not having enough data to fill the pixels of your bitmap.
This is because they use the buffer's remaining() method to figure the capacity of the buffer, which takes into account the current value of its position attribute.  If you call rewind() on your buffer before you invoke copyPixelsFromBuffer(), you should see the runtime exception disappear.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for this issue :

You should always set the `buffer size > bit map size` since The Bitmap on different Android version always changed.

You can log the codes in below to see the `buffer size & bitmap size` (Android API should >= 12 to use following log)

```
Log.i("", "Bitmap size = " + mBitmap.getByteCount());
        Log.i("", "Buffer size = " + mBuffer.capacity());
```

It should be worked.

Thanks,